# How to change bytecode with Byte Buddy?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, byte-buddy

I load a bytecode of class file into a byte array.

I want to change to change with Byte Buddy in order to add the profiler inteceptor.

I google out mang examples. But the examples are `rebase(aClass)`, `redefine(aClass)` or `subclass(aClass)`. No one is parse the bytecode.

The agent builder is near by my idea. But it is used in the agent. I want to use it in the `ClassLoader`.

BTW: *I can change the bytecode with ASM.*

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `ClassFileLocator` in combination with a `TypePool` to create a type description that you can provide to Byte Buddy.

The type pool will query the class file locator for other classes that are linked by the instrumented class if this is necessary. Therefore, you cannot provide a raw byte array only but need to supply a richer structure.

Comment: Thanks Rafael! I was wondering, based on the date this answer was posted on, if some new mechanism has been created in order to allow modifying a class' bytecode even thought TypePool can't find such class' dependencies in the classpath? Because, I think it'd be very handy to take the simplicity of Bute Buddy's API in order to modify just a single class on demand, especially when instrumenting a class at compile time where it's not needed for the class to get loaded.

Comment: Well, unless a class is required to be resolved, Byte Buddy does not resolve it. Did you try it and what exception did you get?

Comment: The use case I'm dealing with only provides me with a single class at a time from which I only get its byte array, so for example, if I have 2 classes in my project, A.class and B.class, when I get the A.class byte array from the API, I use it to create a ByteBuddy instance, if said class has no connection with B.class, it all works well, however, if for example A.class extends B.class, then I get something like "Cannot resolve type description for B". I wanted to intercept some A.class method, just to wrap it with some code, but because it extends B.class, the `rebase` method fails.

Comment: You might be able to avoid it by disabling validation: `new ByteBuddy().with(TypeValidation.DISABLED)`. From the stack trace you should otherwise be able to figure out why B is resolved to see why Byte Buddy requires the information. Your only approach from there would be to avoid this particular action.